# Text cutout of paths body

Tags: svg

I'm currently trying to create the SVG of an old image, however I have trouble creating the correct rotated and positioned text cutout.
When I try to add a `<text>` element it ends up stretched, under the form or is not visible at all.
Here is what I came up with so far:

```html
<svg 
    height="360px"
    width="100%"
    preserveAspectRatio="none"
    viewBox="0 0 100 360"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <path 
            id="banner" 
            d="M0,186 L 100,0 100,186 0,360 Z" 
            fill="#2180b3" 
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#banner" />
</svg>
```

And here is what I'm trying to archive:
[image: Result]
The cutout should be white
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to work on this one, but couldn't quite figured it out. This was the closest I got: https://jsfiddle.net/zc2uter5/1/. The `x` attribute's value is 100/N, where N is the value of the X axis in the scale transform (.2 in the fiddle). It seems wrong, though, and I'm sure there's a better way (I haven't worked much with text in svg), but maybe it'll provide some clues?

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg thank you very much for trying! Actually I solved this by dismissing the idea of putting text in it and drawing the form itself, left arrow , top arrow etc. but dismissed that again and used a oversized div (width width 120%, margin-left -5%, overflow hidden) with right aligned text in it and used css `rotate(-10deg)` on it, which works and renders the same across all devices

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an image to svg converter like [this one](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1280.000000pt" height="376.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 376.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.13, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2015
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,376.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M12700 3702 c-52 -7 -95 -14 -96 -15 -14 -22 -434 -961 -432 -966 2
-5 143 -157 313 -339 l310 -330 3 413 c1 227 1 602 0 832 l-3 418 -95 -13z"/>
<path d="M11785 3569 c-176 -26 -331 -49 -343 -51 -21 -3 0 -33 199 -283 184
-231 223 -276 230 -260 10 28 240 617 246 633 3 6 1 11 -3 11 -5 -1 -153 -23
-329 -50z"/>
<path d="M5440 2648 c-2989 -435 -5436 -792 -5438 -793 -1 -1 -1 -391 0 -866
l3 -864 5592 760 c3076 418 5596 765 5601 770 10 10 441 948 449 976 3 10
-122 155 -352 410 -319 353 -360 394 -388 396 -18 1 -2478 -354 -5467 -789z"/>
<path d="M11818 2058 c-75 -189 -135 -344 -134 -344 1 -2 669 88 732 98 18 2
-14 46 -208 283 -126 154 -234 286 -242 293 -10 10 -38 -52 -148 -330z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: While this works it seems like scaling over different screen sizes (I want to keep it full width at all times, while changing the height as needed), the main reason why I want to convert to SVG, is lost